# How to calculate error in amplitude and standard deviation for Gaussian fitting?

Tags: python, scipy

[Gaussian fit with data which has xerrors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUsoh.png)

I have data that has xerrors and I am fitting a gaussian curve to it using scipy.optimize.curve.fit.
I want to calculate the errors in amplitude and standard deviation of my fit, using the xerrors given.
The sigma parameter mentioned in [SciPy curvefit docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) takes the yerrors. It would be helpful if I can accommodate the xerrors to the error of gaussian parameters.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Curve_fit does not accept x errors. The simplest thing to do here is likely to generate synthetic datasets (each x point point is a gaussian with a given mean and standard deviation), fit them and analyze the statistics of the fit results.

Comment: I calculated the error by fitting the worst datapoints (widest Gaussian fit) and taking the difference between amplitude and stdev of the best and the worst fit. However, the errors in x points are 1sigma errors and calculated amplitude and stddev errors would be greater than 1sigma if I consider the worst fit. Is there any way to estimate 1sigma errors in amplitude and stddev?